# Reasonable value for http.globalAgent.maxSockets

Tags: windows, node.js

How can I determine a reasonable value for http.globalAgent.maxSockets when running on Windows Server 2012?

I'd like to know a general range I can use for testing.

Answer (score 1):

This is very complex to answer, because it depends on how your application is running.

I've done some test with following configurations on my apps

```
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 1;
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 5:
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 20;
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 1000;
```

And the best value has been 20. The problem with my results, is that they may not be correct for your app.

My advice: make some tests as I did :)